# What JS types can MongoDB accept?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

As we know, the mongodb node client allows us to insert javascript data:

```js
collection.insert({
  alpha: 123,
  bravo: "hello",
  charlie: [1, 2, 3],
})
```

My question: does mongo support newer js types, like BigInt and ArrayBuffers?

```js
collection.insert({
  delta: 789623812637812637812631283712983n, // ???
  echo: new Uint8Array([1, 2, 3, 4]).buffer, // ???
})
```

Where can I find information about mongo's support for JS data types and how they are coerced? I've found [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/) documentation, but it doesn't seem at all useful for understanding how javascript types will be coerced

I'm most concerned with ArrayBuffers at the moment: will mongodb automatically coerce ArrayBuffers as BSON "BinData"? when I retrieve my mongodb documents, will I get back the same ArrayBuffers I had inserted, or will they be coerced to a new type? Do I need to shimmy back-and-forth between my app's ArrayBuffers and some mongodb-compatible data type?

Comment: It's not "javascript data". It's just datatypes. Look here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_datatype.htm

Comment: Also: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/

Comment: @Justinas -- isn't it perfectly reasonable to say that the mongodb "nodejs client" allows us to insert javascript data? this question is in the context of the nodejs client -- also, in my question i had already linked that bson-types documentation page and explained why it doesn't seem useful for answering my question

Comment: The linked document clearly list all possible types. Why do you think it is not useful?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit -- because that documentation is incomplete, not offering any information about javascript primitives like bigint or standard objects like arraybuffers -- it has information about strings, and date objects, but not these newer ecmascript types -- it seems intuitive that the mongo node driver might interpret array buffers as bindata, but where can i find these details? are they utterly undocumented? is the documentation incomplete? or have i not yet found the correct documentation page? the linked documentation is not useful because it doesn't remotely answer the question

Comment: as said in the *original question*, about the linked documentation page on bson types: `but it doesn't seem at all useful for understanding how javascript types will be coerced`

Comment: Data types like arraybuffers are not listed, so obviously they are not supported. Be aware, MongoDB stores BSON objects - not JavaScript types. Your initial statement "As we know, the mongodb node client allows us to insert javascript data" is wrong. Maybe your are looking for https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### the mongodb node driver documentation about javascript type support is missing

- there is no documentation for how the mongodb node driver will interpret or coerce javascript primitives or standard objects
- [js-bson 1.1.6 changelog](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/releases/tag/v1.1.6) mentions that `bigint` is not supported

  - *"the library will now throw an error if it detects a bigint value"*
  - the `Long` class has a `fromBigInt` function
- handling of javascript ArrayBuffer is undocumented

  - rumor is that it may be similar to bigint, throwing an error
  - while not directly supported, it may be possible to convert an arraybuffer into a bson binary object, by first converting it the arraybuffer to a node buffer

    ```js
    import {Binary} from "mongodb"

    const arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer()
    const nodeBuffer = Buffer.from(arrayBuffer)
    const mongoBinary = Binary(nodeBuffer)

    collection.insertOne({mongoBinary})
    ```

Comment: https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson#how-do-i-add-custom-serialization-logic

Comment: @D.SM -- that's very useful, thanks for that link about `toBSON` serialization -- i might use that for my custom object ids

Answer (score 2):

The types that MongoDB server understands are listed in the documentation you found, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/. The server does not understand and does not accept any other types.

Your application does not talk to the server directly but does that through a driver. The driver is  responsible for converting basic types of your programming language to the bson types that the server understands. Sometimes this conversion is straightforward, sometimes it is not. For example, the only bson string type requires utf-8 encoding, which the driver may enforce on input strings. Similarly there are languages like Ruby and Python that contain a single integer type which can contain arbitrarily large values; the driver converts those values to one of two bson integer types (32-bit or 64-bit) or errors if the value is too big.

Basic *language* types generally do not include all of the types that are defined by the language's *standard library* (for example, the various collection types may be supported only to the extent that they provide automatic conversions to the basic language array or mapping).

Your driver, or other related libraries, may provide facilities for defining additional type conversions. For example, Mongoid does this via [custom fields](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/mongoid-documents/#custom-fields).

Consult your driver documentation for what type conversions are provided and how they work. Example for Ruby: https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/bson-v4/#supported-classes

Comment: "Consult your driver documentation" -- this is exactly what i cannot find -- "Sometimes this conversion is straightforward, sometimes it is not." -- exactly my issue: my question is, how would the mongodb node driver handle bigint and array buffers? is there a straightforward conversion, or not, and where could i find this information? -- i understand that the node driver is performs type conversions, but my question is about two specific conversions, and where can i find that information?

Comment: `The driver is responsible for converting basic types of your programming language to the bson types that the server understands` -- this is exactly the mysteriously undocumented information i seek, for the node driver -- is this simply undocumented? -- i can imagine that mongodb basically supported all json types, which was straightforward, and so the authors felt the documentation was unnecessary: but now in 2021, there are new javascript primitives like bigint and standard objects like arraybuffer, which appear undocumented?

Comment: Which documentation did you already check?

Comment: the same documentation that i had originally linked in the question itself, where i explained why i didn't find it useful

Comment: That documentation is for the server, not for node driver.

Comment: yes exactly, which is why i explained that it's *not useful*.. are we on the same page?

Comment: Finding node driver documentation is a basic task that any developer should be able to do.

Comment: except that the documentation does not exist on this topic, that is the essense of the problem and thus this whole question, isn't it?

Comment: and of course,i've been relentlessly searching for more information... i managed to find a changelog that mentioned that `bigint` is not supported and will throw an error, but i can't find any formal documentation on this topic -- it seems very strange to me, that mongodb's node driver has no documentation for how javascript data is interpreted -- i suppose it makes more sense historically, back when there were fewer javascript types, and that this created a blindspot for the mongo maintainers, and as the modern javascript ecosystem has since evolved, the documentation has not kept pace

Comment: Add your research to the question including links to information you did find.

Comment: thanks for your help. i've formalized my research as an answer